# Getting the math straight in algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am trying to get the math correct in my algorithm, but I am having a really hard time understanding the "Analysis of algorithms" calculating i.e `f(n) = 1` or `f(n) = n-1` etc..

I have created a method which loops through a sorted array of integers, and counting how many different integers there are (i.e `{1,3,3,3,5,6,8} = 5`). How do I calculate the worst case scenario?

Basically, the code is like this:

```
int length = a.length;
int diffCount = 1; //The number of different integers

for(int i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
    int b = a[i];
    int c = a[i-1];

    if(c>b)
         throw new IllegalStateException("unsorted array");

    if(c!=b)
         diffCount++;
}
return diffCount;
```

There's some other stuff there aswell, but that's just to prevent bugs like empty arrays and such, so I didn't include it.

And what is the worst case scenario here..? If the condition `c!=b` is true every time?

Comment: you need to look at every entry in the array - so the worst case is a new value each time. the best - the same vale each time. the 'length' of the algorithm is the same in either case.

Comment: There is no real worst case scenario, you will always iterate over the entire array, so, even if the entire array is {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} you will check every number, it's linear, you will always iterate over a.length elements, the + operator is really cheap, and the int variable has it's memory already allocated, the plus operator, the if condition are static, costs exactly 1, you could say the worst case would be to add +1 to the diff counter every time, but it's a static cost, let's say, the worst case would be 2*a.lenght, the best 1*a.lenght, but its a static cost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of run-time analysis, this algorithms is always *O(n)*, if the array is sorted. If not, it will throw an exception before that (but worst case still is *O(n)*).

There are slightly different outcomes depending on the values. See Peter's answer for an explanation of branch prediction. But I don't think that this will influence the run time significantly.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be O(n-1)? I start the loop at 1, ending at <length, while also checking the last element..?

Comment: *O(n-1)=O(n)-O(1)* and since *O(1)* is dominated by *O(n)*, *O(n-1)=O(n)* (as assylias stated)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the time it take to execute this loop will always be the same for a given length of array.

I looked at whether the branch prediction might suffer, it it appears in this case it doesn't possibly because the JIT is smart enough to eliminate the second branch.

In C the branch could be removed with

```
diffCount += c != b;
```

and possibly the JIT does something similar.

Comment: Only if you assume that the array is sorted... ;)

Comment: Cool addition, that brought back a piece of knowledge I lost a few years ago right after I learned it in a computer science course. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when analysing complexity, you focus on what you think the slowest operation in the algorithm is. For sorting algorithms, I believe you pick the comparison. In your code, I'd pick the two array accesses:

```
int b = a[i];
int c = a[i-1];
```

or even the comparison of the two:

```
if (c != b) …
```

instead of `diffCount++`. This means that the result of the comparison isn't important since it always occurs.

Of course you can choose to analyse the complexity in terms of more than one operation. E.g. for sorts, you can look at the element swaps as well as element comparisons. Or in your case you might want to focus on `diffCount++` because you expect the memory write to be much slower than the comparison.

The operations I'd choose get hit `a.length` times, so that's your algorithm's complexity.

If this chosen operation is under a condition, you have to pick (when looking for Big-O complexity) a reasonable *upper* bound on how often the condition can get hit. So, in your case, if it's possible for any input array that `c != b` is true for all pairs of elements checked, you can assume it's always true in your analysis.

Comment: I have also created a similar method for unsorted arrays, which uses nested loops to check if the int at i already has been passed. So in first loop, it adds one to diffCount, in the second round of the loop, it loops through `for(int j = 0; j<i; j++)` and checks if the first int was the same. If it wasn't, then it adds another to diffCount. I believe that the answer here would be n^2 IF the nested loop also had `j<length`(?), but as it only needs to check the previous checked integers, how do I write that? Some summation/factional-stuff? Or am I completely wrong by accounting the nested loop?

Comment: @StianF If the nested loop only checks the previously checked integers, it needs to run a total of `sum(1..n)` times which is `(n/2)(n+1) = (n^2 + n)/2`. In Big-O, you focus on the dominant factor, so you can ignore the `n` and the division by 2, and say it's still `O(n^2)`

Comment: @StianF It's of course important to know whether you're trying to determine the exact or asymptotic complexity – when doing the latter, you can handwave like this.